# How can i set Dynamic Header in mail using codeigniter ?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to set a Dynamic Header on mail header when i send mail. I don't want to do it with **SMPT** server and if it will be in **codeigniter**, so it will be greate. You will get idea what exactly i want by given image bellow.

from: **Google** < dynamic email@gmail.com >

[image]

**My Code**

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['send'])) {

  //Email information
  $email = $_POST['email'];
  $subject = $_POST['subject'];
  $comment = $_POST['comment'];

  //send email
  mail($email, "$subject", $comment, "From:" . $email);

  //Email response
  echo "Thank you for contacting us!";
}

//if "email" variable is not filled out, display the form
else {
?>
  <form method="post" name="testmail">
    Email: <input name="email" type="text" />
    Subject: <input name="subject" type="text" />
    Message:<textarea name="comment" rows="15" cols="40"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" name="send" value="Submit" />
  </form>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: If you are using CodeIgniter, why aren't you using the email library provided by the framework?

Comment: my mail is working Properly. i just want to set up dynamic header which shown in image above.

Comment: You can set those headers using CodeIgniter, read the docs.

Comment: there is nothing to set dynamic header in codeignter...thnks...

Comment: Are you familiar with mvc? Or codeigniter for that matter?

Comment: yes , i have only problem that i want to make header from dynamic.

Answer (score -1):

use like this:

mail(to,subject,message,headers,parameters);

Comment: It  is not working . Its showing errors like **Unable to send email using PHP Sendmail. Your server might not be configured to send mail using this method.**

Comment: can u suggest me how to configure it, i have linux base server.